# Parsing XML with nodes containing HTML in Qt

Tags: qt, html-parsing, xml-parsing

I try to parse an XML file with some nodes containing HTML in Qt, it looks like this:

```
<root>
 <list>
  <element>Some <i>text<i></element>
  <element><b>another line of text<b></element>
  <element><i>Tag opened here</element>
  <element>and closed here</i></element>
 </list>
</root>
```

I tried different approaches in Qt, but getting the HTML from the  node was somehow not possible (in an easy way).

**QDomDocument**: 
The only way I found to get the text of a QDomElement:
Use the save() function ([documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdomnode.html#save)), but then I would get the whole line "<element>...</element>", not just the inner text.

**QXmlStreamReader** 
There is the function readElementText(QXmlStreamReader::IncludeChildElements) ([documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText)), but it removes the HTML tags, so the text of the first example would be only "Some text".

Can this be done in a more effective way?

I thought of another solution, what do you think about it:

How about wrapping the contents of the <element> tags in CDATA sections (using string replace or regex functions) before the xml file is parsed?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser/490395#490395

Answer (score 1):

Neither QDomDocument nor QXmlStreamReader is able to parse HTML. They are XML parsers. To parse HTML in Qt you should use QtWebKit.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString html =
    "                                                   \\
    <root>                                              \\
     <list>                                             \\
      <element>Some <i>text<i></element>                \\
      <element><b>another line of text<b></element>     \\
      <element><i>Tag opened here</element>             \\
      <element>and closed here</i></element>            \\
     </list>                                            \\
    </root>                                             \\
    ";

    QWebPage page;
    page.mainFrame()->setHtml(html);
    QWebElement htmlElement = page.mainFrame()->findFirstElement("root list element i");
    qDebug() << htmlElement.toPlainText();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
"text"
```

Answer (score 0):

The dom method of doing it should be nodeValue().